# Three js lensflare render outside

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, light

I want ask about THREE.js lensflare. When my camera dont show my lensflare, its in second dissapear. Is there any option to set something like offset to my camera.. to not hide my lensflare like this?

Here is gif with my problem.

[image]

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any option to set something like offset to my camera?

No. The only thing you can do is a modification of `THREE.Lensflare`.

Comment: and how can I modife it to do what I want?

Comment: Remove this [line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/objects/Lensflare.js#L347) and this [if statement](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/objects/Lensflare.js#L190) (so the code inside the if statement is always executed). I've not tested the code but it should enforce to always render the lensflares.

Comment: Great! Its working, thanks for show me direction, now i just will edit lensflare.js to achieve what i want

Comment: i just edited this two lines and its working great :) [line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/objects/Lensflare.js#L173)

Comment: is ok that i have now two lensflare and second lensflare is exactly same but only position is reverted (x is now -10 not 10, etc) When I uncomment this [line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/objects/Lensflare.js#L347) I have again only one lensflare on right place. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really. The hack seems to works only for a single lensflare effect.

Comment: In code I have just one lensflare, but when I commented that lines it create me another lensflare but with reverted position, maybe just lensflare come across all scene in that way..